# Filter :nth-child ignoring where css display is none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a script that takes some floating divs in columns of 3 gets the largest height from the 3 columns on 1 row and makes all 3 divs the same height. It then repeats it for each row, the script works fine however I have built a custom filter system in JQuery that makes certain divs hidden or shown depending on the selection of price range, or brand etc.

When I am using the filter it will then remove say column 2 of the top row and make column 4 of the second row move up to the top row. Leaving column 2 in the code and so re-running the height/column check script will not work.

So what I am trying to do is where I am using my `filter(':nth-child(3n-2)')` add an if statement that will skip all div's that are hidden from the :nth-child selection.

I do understand I can use a function inside my `filter();` but its a function that's new to me so am unsure on how to use it exactly.

Here is my working code:

```
var $sections = $('.section-link');
$sections.filter(':nth-child(3n-2)').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $els = $this.nextAll(':lt(2)').addBack();
    var sectionheight = new Array();
    $els.each(function () {
        var value = $(this).find('.section-title').height();
        sectionheight.push(value);
    });
    var newsectionheight = Math.max.apply(Math, sectionheight);
    $els.find('.section-title').height(newsectionheight);
})
```

## [JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bk6V3/)

Am trying to use something like this so far:

```
$sections.filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
}, ':nth-child(3n-2)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay managed to get it working by returning the css property before calling the :nth-child

```
function makeheight(){
var $sections = $('.section-link');

    $sections.filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('display') == 'block';
}, ':nth-child(3n-2)').each(function () {

        var $this = $(this),
            $els = $this.nextAll(':lt(2)').addBack();
        var sectionheight = new Array();
        $els.each(function () {
            var value = $(this).find('.section-title').height();
            sectionheight.push(value);
        });
        var newsectionheight = Math.max.apply(Math, sectionheight);
        $els.find('.section-title').height(newsectionheight);
    });


}
```